# How to change variable names in runtime

Tags: c#, loops, xamarin

I have a loop that I need to create `Entries` dynamically, and with that, I need to `setFocus()` on a specifically `Entry`, and then, another one, etc.

How can I change the name of variables in runtime to I identify it?

```
for(i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  //the result that I want:
  Entry entry + i = new Entry(){ Placeholder = "Entry number" + i.ToString() };
}

//result
entry1 =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 1";
entry2 =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 2";
entry3 =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 3";
```

EDIT:

I forgot to put an Entry event that I need to use:

```
entries[i].Completed += (s, e) =>
{
   if (!entries[i].Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
   {
    entries[i].Text += "\u00b2";
   }
};
   entries[i].Focus();
```

when it enters in this event, it can't know how entry that I'm calling, always get the last entry of this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use some kind of collection, for example an array:

```
var entries = new Entry[3];
for(i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  //the result that I want:
  entries[i] = new Entry(){ Placeholder = "Entry number" + i.ToString() };
}

//result
entries[0] =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 1";
entries[1] =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 2";
entries[2] =  /* Placeholder */ "Entry number 3";
```

To know the called entry you can either cast the sender parameter like Jason suggests, `var entry = (Entry)s`. Or capture a variable:

```
// for loops require copying of the index to a local variable when capturing. 
var currentIndex = i; 
entries[i].Completed += (s, e) =>
{
   if (!entries[currentIndex].Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
   {
    entries[currentIndex].Text += "\u00b2";
   }
};
```

Variable names mostly exist before compilation, so asking how to change it at runtime is kind of a nonsensical question.

Comment: I updated my question, I forgot to put a few lines that I'm struggling to do. Can you please edit your answer and include what I asked now?

Answer (score 2):

the `s` in the event parameters is the **sender** - that is, the object that fired the event

```
entries[i].Completed += (s, e) =>
{
   var entry = (Entry)s;

   if (!entry.Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
   {
     entry.Text += "\u00b2";
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    entries[i].Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
       if (!entries[i].Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
       {
          entries[i].Text += "\u00b2";
       }
    };
}
```

you "[capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)" that `i` *variable* in that event handler, not its *value*. This means that when that Completed event finally fires, it uses the latest known value of "i".

The solution is to copy the value to a new variable, declared inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    entries[j].Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
       if (!entries[j].Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
       {
          entries[j].Text += "\u00b2";
       }
    };
}
```